# Spring Boot @Value annotaion return null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to put api key in application.properties and get api key from it.

So I put api key in application.properties.

application.properties

```
server.port=8090

#My Key will be placed in here
shortweather.key=myapikey
```

And then I made a class to get api key from application.properties

ApiKey.java class

```
package com.wook.weather;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ApiKey {
    @Value("${shortweather.key}")
    private String apiKey;

    public String getApiKey() {
        return apiKey;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ApiKey [apiKey=" + apiKey + "]";
    }
    
}
```

And I made an instance at main method and try to call **getApiKey()**

Application.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import org.springframework.web.util.DefaultUriBuilderFactory;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    private final static String BASE_URL = "http://apis.data.go.kr/1360000/VilageFcstInfoService_2.0";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        
        String serviceKey = "apikey";
        String pageNo = "1";
        String numOfRows = "12";
        String dataType = "JSON";
        String base_date = "20211020";
        String base_time = "2300";
        String nx = "55";
        String ny = "127";

        DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(BASE_URL);
        factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY);

        WebClient wc = WebClient.builder().uriBuilderFactory(factory).baseUrl(BASE_URL).build();

        String response = wc.get()
                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/getVilageFcst")
                        .queryParam("serviceKey", serviceKey)
                        .queryParam("numOfRows", numOfRows)
                        .queryParam("pageNo", pageNo)
                        .queryParam("dataType", dataType)
                        .queryParam("base_date", base_date)
                        .queryParam("base_time", base_time)
                        .queryParam("nx", nx)
                        .queryParam("ny", ny).build())
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();

        System.out.println(response);
        
        
        //I made ApiKey instance here
        ApiKey apk = new ApiKey();
        //This part return null
        System.out.println(apk.getApiKey());
    }
}
```

But I get null.

I want to get value that is in application.properties.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Spring only injects value while the bean is managed by spring. You are creating an instance of the bean by calling new. This is where you are taking control of yourself and spring is no longer able to inject value. Rather you should do this:

```
@Autowired
private ApiKey apk;
```

And also you marked the ApiKey class with @Component. So, spring will create an instance and then inject it to the main call by auto wiring. And when spring takes control over instantiation, you will get your desired value.

Complete code:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    
        private final ApiKey apk;
    
        public Application( ApiKey apk ) {
            this.apk = apk;
        }
    
    
        public static void main( String[] args ) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void run( String... args ) throws Exception {
            
            String serviceKey = "apikey";
            String pageNo = "1";
            String numOfRows = "12";
            String dataType = "JSON";
            String base_date = "20211020";
            String base_time = "2300";
            String nx = "55";
            String ny = "127";
    
            DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(BASE_URL);
            factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY);
    
            WebClient wc = WebClient.builder().uriBuilderFactory(factory).baseUrl(BASE_URL).build();
    
            String response = wc.get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/getVilageFcst")
                            .queryParam("serviceKey", serviceKey)
                            .queryParam("numOfRows", numOfRows)
                            .queryParam("pageNo", pageNo)
                            .queryParam("dataType", dataType)
                            .queryParam("base_date", base_date)
                            .queryParam("base_time", base_time)
                            .queryParam("nx", nx)
                            .queryParam("ny", ny).build())
                    .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
    
            System.out.println(response);
            System.out.println(apk.getApiKey());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have `@Autowired ApiKey` but I get this issue. `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field apk.` Why is this error is happening? I have made a bean and Auto wired it.

Comment: Oh sorry....I have not noticed. The main method is static. So, you can not call a non-static here. but there are other ways. Wait a bit, I will update my ans

Comment: @superRookie hey I have updated my answer. If this help then please upvote and accept my answer.